# Having only one instance of an entity in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am making an application where you need to log in with a 4 digit password but there can only be one password at a time. I am trying to save it to core data but whenever the user adds a new password it just adds it to the long list. How can I restrict an entity to only have one instance of itself?

Here is my code just in case it will help:

```
-(BOOL)savePassword:(NSString*)password{
    AppDelegate * appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc]init];
    NSManagedObjectContext * context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    AppData * appData = (AppData*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AppData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    appData.password = password;
    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AppData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
        NSLog(@"There was an error:%@",error);
    }

    for (AppData * adata in fetchedObjects) {
        NSLog(@"Password:%@",adata.password);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Fetch and edit instead of adding? And why are you creating a new app delegate each time?

Comment: You should not create a new Managed Object every time. You must update it if it exist. So check if there is an object, if not create else update previous.

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Hmm, @C_X so now that I tried your advice, I am getting an error that says: Terminating app due to uncaught exception. I added this code: `if (appData == nil){
    appData = (AppData*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AppData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    appData.password = password;}
    else if(appData != nil){
    appData.password = password;}`

Comment: In the general case, read [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4)

Comment: Storing passwords in Core Data is a terrible idea. The data store is not encrypted. Use the suggested techniques from this answer to store your singleton instance, but don't include a password attribute. Instead, use the keychain to store the encrypted password for whatever user crendentials are stored in your AppData entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do like this, first create fetch request and execute a fetch. check if object exist, update data. else if no data exist create an object and save it. 
If name of entity which is storing password.
Your code should look like this

```
AppData * appData;
 NSManagedObjectContext * context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AppData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
 [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

 NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
 if(fetchObjects.count > 0){
      appData = [fetchObjects objectAtIndex:0];//assume there will be one object

      // and do reset of thing
 }
  else{

       appData = (AppData*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AppData" inManagedObjectContext:context];

 }
 appData.password = password;
 // save moc here
 [context save:nil];
```

Comment: Its formated now! yes we can check for the error! here I just right min code which could solve the above mentioned problem.

Comment: @C_X Did you mean to have the `appData.password = password;
 // save moc here
 [context save:nil];` in the else statement?

Comment: no it is out of the block, as It setting password will happen in both sides. and context should be save after that, if and else is only to make sure if it is already exist or not

Comment: @C_X And also on line 9 why would we want to set AppData itself to whatever is at position 0? Wouldn't we want to set AppData.password?

Comment: Okay let me explain, at first line we have only a pointer pointing to nothing, after that we create fetch request, and execute it. It return us an array of objects. Now if array count is greater than zero its means we have object already and we will not create new. and we just set appdata pointer to the object. And we are assuming that ther is only one object so we are using index 0. If count is zero then we will create new object and will assign it to pointer appdata, so we can use it. now we have appdata we sill set password, and will save MOC.

Comment: @C_X Ok finally I got everything working. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 5):

The right approach here is to **not put this data in Core Data**. If you only have one instance, there's no point in using Core Data to solve the problem. There's no benefit to using Core Data for this. Put it somewhere else. Code solutions miss the point, because even if it works, it's a bad design.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment on the question instead of an answer?

Comment: @TomHarrington But I am trying to save the password to the device. Should I be using something like a plist?

Comment: If we have multiple fields  for example: AppPreferences, then we need this kind of implementation.

Comment: App preferences should go in `NSUserDefaults`, or just possibly in a custom file. Multiple fields is not a reason to use Core Data.